# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl32 in java.library.path

Tags: java

I am using Linux Mint 17.3.(32 bit operating system). I am trying to make a simple OpenGL program using LWJGL library in **NetBeans** but it shows following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl32 in java.library.path
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: If you have got the LWJGL library in your local drive, you can configure the build path to include that library.

Comment: I can use this library in windows 32 bit system but in my Linux Mint its not working. The LWJGL library is in my home directory.

Comment: I believe the LWJGL library is not yet added to the JVM build path in your Linux Mint. Can you edit the question to include more information? How do you start the program in Linux Mint? Is it NetBeans as well?